# How to get exclude text of anchor tag in xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

What should be xPath if I only want to extract error message " Error Message: Invalid Entry " but not the 'x' between

```html
<div id="super" class="small-00 columns">
  <div id="sub" class="sub error">
  Error Message: Invalid Entry
  <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
  </div>   
</div>
```

I have tried

```
$x("//div[@id='sub']")
```

Comment: maybe with `//div[@id="sub"]/text()` ?

Comment: `$x("//div[@id='sub']")` is not a valid `Selenium` XPAth, it's only allowed in a real browser dev tools or https://pptr.dev

Answer (score 1):

Tested with `xmllint`:

```
$ cat file
<div id="super" class="small-00 columns">
  <div id="sub" class="sub error">
  Error Message: Invalid Entry
  <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
  </div>   
</div>

$ xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@id="sub"]/text()' file

  Error Message: Invalid Entry
```

Comment: This does not work when I put run in Selenium4 /JUnit4

Comment: Define 'does not work'

Comment: Out put  is 

"Error Message: Invalid Entry /n x"

Comment: Show us your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

//div[contains(text(),'Error Message: Invalid Entry')]/text()

Try this it will capture all the XPath matching with text
Error Message: Invalid Entry

Comment: This is not correct solution. It still captures `x`